# How to set guides at a certain position in mm

Tags: gimp

I need to design a front panel, so I created a new image with 300dpi and the size of 397mm by 127mm. To draw the holes for the different ports I need to place them at a certain x,y position.

With

```
Image\Guides\New Guide...
```

I can add a new guide, but only at the pixel position and not in mm.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CAD program or something like SVG?

I'm partial to postscript

```
%!PS
/inch { 72 mul } def
1 inch 1 inch  5 inch 2 inch rectstroke
/Helvetica 36 selectfont
2 inch 2.5 inch moveto (Acme Widget) show
newpath
2 inch 1.5 inch 0.3 inch 0 360 arc stroke
/Helvetica-bold 12 selectfont
2.5 inch 1.5 inch moveto (Volume) show
2.3 inch 1.2 inch moveto (11) show
showpage
```

[image: Postscript image]

Answer (score 0):

On Gimp 2.8, the ["Comics-o-matic" GIMP plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/28631) by ilguido can do this.  However, it is not designed for single guides, so you get a few extras that are easy to remove.

Download the plugin (.scm file) and put it in your `.gimp-2.8/scripts` directory, then restart GIMP.  (On Windows 7, `c:\users\<yourname>\.gimp-2.8\scripts`.)  Open your image and go to the new "Comics-o-matic" menu.  Select `Guides` | `Add Guides (framing)`.  You will see the following dialog box:

[image: Screenshot of Add Guides dialog box]

Set "Columns" and "Rows" to 1 and then specify your guide positions in the top, bottom, left, and right margin boxes.  You can use mm or 32nds of an inch (pick in the Units box).  If you only want one guide, put its position in the Top margin (for horizontal) or Left margin (for vertical), and use 0 for the other dimensions.  Hit OK and you will get four guides for your margins.  Drag the ones you don't want off the image using the Move tool.  Dragging off is especially easy if you selected margin 0, because you only have to move them a pixel outside the image to make them disappear.